# Ion input hides below keyboard - ionic 2

Tags: input, keyboard, ionic2

First see the code:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>
      <ion-input placeholder="First Name" [value]="fName" [(ngModel)]="fName"></ion-input>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>
      <ion-input placeholder="Last Name" [value]="lName" [(ngModel)]="lName"></ion-input>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12>
      <ion-input type="email" [disabled]="emailDisabled" placeholder="Email" [value]="email" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12>
      <ion-input type="tel" maxlength="10" placeholder="Mobile Number" [value]="mobile" [(ngModel)]="mobile"></ion-input>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

The problem is: When any of the ion-input is focused & keyboard appears, it hides below the keyboard. I want it to scroll above the keyboard, so that it remain visible. How can I achieve this?

Edit1:
When I started typing in input field, it scrolls up & visible.

Thanks

Comment: Is this in the footer?

Comment: no. All in ion-content.

Comment: not sure if it helps.. had a similar issue with `ion-textarea` in footer in ios.. I switched to html element `textarea` and it worked..Try using `input`.. You will have to fully customize with css though

Comment: Pure html <input> will not have ngModel or value. Am I wrong?

Comment: angular will take care of that.. ngModel will still work..

Comment: I replaced my ion-input with input but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem on Android & solve this bug from the following Post on git

[Ionic 2 On-Screen Keyboard Covers Focused Input Element Inside Grid Component](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10629#issuecomment-284776902)

I solved the problem adding the **`style position: initial to ion-col`** elements.